# Error with dynamically adding controls

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate, dynamic-controls

I have a `UserControl`. I dynamically create some controls (Columns for `SPGridView`. Grid control was added in markup, `ObjectDataSource`, `Button` and `Label`) in `CreateChildControl` method and add them to `Controls` collection. Two of these controls are added well (`Button` and `Label`) in postback, but one of them (`MenuTemplate`) raise the exception with such content:

> "*Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is
>   being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save
>   viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding
>   controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match
>   the type and position of the controls added during the initial
>   request.* "

When I move my code to `OnInit` method all controls are added successfully. So, I have a question: **Could someone explain me why some controls are added to Controls collection successfully and others are failed  in `CreateChildControls` in postback?** I have read about ViewState [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms972976.aspx). Probably I didn't understand some moments.

Look at me code:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{

 Label l = new Label();
 l.ID = "labelTest";
 l.Text = "Hello test!";

 Button b = new Button();
 b.Text = "Press test";
 b.ID = "buttonTest";
 b.Click += b_Click;

 Controls.Add(l);
 Controls.Add(b);

 ObjectDataSource gridDataSource = new ObjectDataSource();
 gridDataSource.ID = "gridDataSource";
 gridDataSource.SelectMethod = "GetDataSource";
 gridDataSource.TypeName = this.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;

 Controls.Add(gridDataSource);

 SPMenuField colMenu = new SPMenuField();
 colMenu.HeaderText = "Test";
 colMenu.TextFields = "Test";
 colMenu.MenuTemplateId = "ListMenu";

 // it is my SPGridView that added in markup
 customGridView.Columns.Add(colMenu);

 MenuTemplate titleListMenu = new MenuTemplate();
 titleListMenu.ID = "ListMenu";

 // The exception occurs here
 Controls.Add(titleListMenu);

 base.CreateChildControls();
}
```

Comment: I hope you are aware of the page life cycle. Control added in Page_Load will not have viewstate. The Viewstate is build earlier to this.

Comment: I think that controls will have viewstate in Page_Load. See [this explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic3), Figure 4. Events and View State

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can only add items into a template in Page_Load or other events(ie, after Page_Init) so that it will be retained in postback, not the template itself.. Templates are need to be created before or at Page_Init stage, otherwise it may not load the controls into that templates from viewstate or may result in error.